# How can I recognize whether a string is a UDID for an iOS device?

Tags: objective-c, regex, cocoa, udid

I'm working on an iOS Cocoa app that has a fallback - if the user doesn't enter a certain piece of data, the device's UDID is used instead, as a default. I need to add a check in our server code (written in Ruby) to recognize whether the value being sent up is a UDID (the user's default) or a custom string that they've set.

It seems that the right solution to my problem is a regular expression. I'm comfortable writing regex'es, but I need to be certain that this regex is 100% guaranteed to recognize a UDID.

I retrieve the UDID in code using:

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier]
```

And in the simulator, I get back this value:

```
6938CA7D-ECE2-53A4-B293-961A8D07AFB1
```

From this I might infer that I can just search for a string of hex characters that matches the pattern 8-4-4-4-12. But I want to be certain this works for every UDID.

I can't find anything about this in Apple's documentation and was wondering if anyone could give me a definitive answer to this question... thanks!

Comment: Minor comment: what if more than one user provide the same string?

Comment: nothing to do with iPhone, cocoa or IOS, its a Ruby question right ?

Comment: Real problem is software behavior design. UDID just identifies **devices**, not people. Person can't be identified reliably with UDID. And using UDID may cause many problems because user can't change UDID.

Comment: @VdesmedT I didn't see anything to do with Ruby in this so edited tags to replace Ruby with objective-c and cocoa. In fact it has NOTHING to do with Ruby whatsoever but everything to do with Cocoa and objective-c. And since it's an iOS app it also has everything to do with iOS. Not sure if question was changed but I can't see how you missed that.

Comment: Actually I specified that I am looking for a way to detect this in my server code, which is Ruby-based; I was rather expecting Ruby syntax for regular expressions to show up among the answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not send another bit of data indicating that it is a UDID? Or just use a different parameter name (`UDID=6938...`).

Then, in your server, you can test it like so if you really want to:

```
# somewhere outside the controller action, maybe the top of the file
UDID_PATTERN = /\A[a-f0-9]{8}-[a-f0-9]{4}-[a-f0-9]{4}-[a-f0-9]{4}-[a-f0-9]{12}\Z/

# inside the controller action you're sending info to
udid = params[:UDID]
if udid && (udid =~ UDID_PATTERN)
  # do something with the UDID in place of the other
  # bit of info they could have provided
end
```

Comment: Marking this as the answer; it's true that there's no truly reliable way except for explicitly flagging it, and as another poster pointed out, it seems that devices produce different UDID's than simulators, which is another quirk that seems to prove that these UDID's aren't very predictable. But the regex provided is a valid one for recognizing a string matching the pattern I posted in Ruby code.

Comment: The given pattern fails for so many valid UDIDs.Now a days there are UDIDs without hyphen too.

Answer (score 2):

You can't tell. Apple's [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDevice/uniqueIdentifier) says:

> A device’s unique identifier (sometimes abbreviated as UDID for Unique Device Identifier) is a hash value composed from various hardware identifiers such as the device serial number.

The iPhone simulator returns a different value for the `uniqueIdentifier` compared to real iOS devices. All of the real iPhone devices I've used have UDIDs that are 40 hex characters. But it's best not to make any assumptions.

Even if there were a UDID pattern, what if the user entered something that matched that pattern?

Answer (score 2):

Obviously, the only guaranteed way is adding additional field which marks whether your user entered expected data or not.

UDID form and algorithm is not published, and not designed to be detected again. So determining might be possible, but it never be 100%.